# Rotating Backup solution - Windows User data

Tags: windows, backup

I've been looking around here and Googling but I couldn't find what I'm looking for.  Recently I formatted a guy's PC as its Windows partition had gone corrupt.  Thankfully the guy that came before me made daily backups of the user data.  Now I would like to add the same safety net back to the clean system.  However I'm not sure which tool(s) are best for this.

The way the tool worked was in my eyes very nice.

It had a monthly rotating system.
A backup folder containing
-dag 1
-dag 2
-...
-dag31

And in each folder all user related data was stored but not a full backup from each day; it appeared to keep a diff.  So even tough this tool had been running for 5 years, it only required around 10GB of space.  The logic was if the file location known previously had changed it would copy that file to the backup location, and if nothing had changed no new backup was taken.

I would love to install the same tool, but I can't find it.

Any worthy replacement will help as well.  So all suggestions are welcome.  Preferably Freeware.

Comment: What OS are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You could do some scripts to automate this via powershell / VBscripts or you could use cobian backup (has a freeware version )or use roaming profiles (they have maintenance overhead ) and manage the backups from that level .

Comment: +1 for Cobian backup. I use it anywhere I have to support Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rsnapshot to do this on Linux machines, and it appears that you can use it to achieve the same on Windows machines.

I have not tried the Windows solution, but you can read more about it on http://www.stillnetstudios.com/snapshot-backups-howto/.

To understand how rsnapshot works, you can have a look at Wikipedia's article about [Hard Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) as well as rsnapshot's own section "[How It Works](http://www.rsnapshot.org/howto/1.2/rsnapshot-HOWTO.en.html#how_it_works)".

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "incremental backup" 
If you want to search those keywords you'll get plenty of results.

On windows clients common choices are cobian backup, windows integrated backup utility, synckbackSE

but there are literally tons of options available